# Error : file not found for only one promise with promise.all and ssh2-sftp-client

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, sftp, writefile

I am facing an issue with fs.writeFile() and Promise.all.

I have a script that takes a file from a dropbox, save it on a server and send it to several SFTPs so they can use it. The problem I have is that I always have one of my promise that throws an error saying that the file does not exist. I suspect a problem with aynscrhonous process but I can't find out what I did wrong.

I am using ssh2-sftp-client and fs packages.

Please find below an extract of my code :

```
//I just got the dropboxfile with promise 
.then(function(data) {
    myDownloadedFile = data.name
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
            fs.writeFile(myDownloadedFile, data.fileBinary, 'binary', function (err) {
                if (err) { 
                    throw err
                    rej("file not saved")
                } else {
                    log.info('File save : ' + data.name)
                    res()
                }
            })
        })
    })
    //FTP sending
    .then(function() {
        return Promise.all([sendFiletoFTP(myConnection1, "partner1"), sendFiletoFTP(myConnection2, "partner2"), sendFiletoFTP(myConnection3, "partner3")])
    })
```

And below the sendFiletoFTP function :

```
var sendFiletoFTP = function(FTPObj, myPartenaire) {
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        let sftp = new Client();
        sftp.connect(FTPObj).then(() => {
            return sftp.put(myDownloadedFile, myDownloadedFile)
        })
        .then((data) => {
            sftp.end()
        })
        .then(() => {
            log.info("OK pour " + myPartenaire + " : " + myDownloadedFile);
            res()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            rej(error)
        })
    })
}
```

The error I got is :  Error: File not found which is triggered during sftp.put() action.

Do you have any idea about what could be wrong ?

Comment: I don't see what is causing the error, but please don't `throw` in the promise constructor callback: although that works in your case, you never execute `rej()`. Better leave out the `throw` and do the `rej()`. Also, your second function does not need to create a new promise. Just return the `sftp.connect( ).then( ).then( )` chain, without the call to `res` and without the `catch`.

Comment: `myDownloadedFile` looks global (or must exist in a scope that encloses both code snippets), so something *may* be clobbering it before the sending finishes? ... why not change `sendFiletoFTP` to accept a filename `var sendFiletoFTP = function(FTPObj, myPartenaire, filename) {` and then call like `sendFiletoFTP(myConnection1, "partner1", myDownloadedFile ), ...`

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your first snippet seems to have a combination of arrow vs regular functions for no apparent reason! Why not use arrow functions anywhere they are *appropriate*

`myDownloadedFile` looks global (or must exist in a scope that encloses both code snippets), so something may be clobbering it before the sending finishes?

Now, by passing the `filename` to the `sendFiletoFTP` function, you can ensure some global *doesn't* get "clobbered" before the asynchronous stuff finishes 
- which is what I suspect is happening, but without seeing all the relevant code, that's just a guess. In the code below, the first Promise is resolved to `data.name`, 
removing the need for any var, because the name is the argument to the `.then` that starts the FTP process

Rewrite the first snippet as follows:

```
.then(data => new Promise((res,rej) => 
    fs.writeFile(myDownloadedFile, data.fileBinary, 'binary', err => {
        if (err) { 
            rej("file not saved");
        } else {
            log.info('File save : ' + data.name);
            res(data.name);
        }
    })
))
//FTP sending
.then(filename => Promise.all([
        sendFiletoFTP(myConnection1, "partner1", filename), 
        sendFiletoFTP(myConnection2, "partner2", filename), 
        sendFiletoFTP(myConnection3, "partner3", filename)
    ])
);
```

sendFiletoFTP doesn't need a new Promise constructor, as Client().connect returns a promise already. Adding the extra argument, then function becomes

```
var sendFiletoFTP = function (FTPObj, myPartenaire, myDownloadedFile) {
    return new Client().connect(FTPObj)
    .then(() => sftp.put(myDownloadedFile, myDownloadedFile))
    .then(data => sftp.end())
    .then(() => log.info("OK pour " + myPartenaire + " : " + myDownloadedFile));
};
```